# How to wait for uninstaller to finish?

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

Using NSIS, I want to launch an uninstaller and wait for it to finish before proceeding with my installer.  The problem is the uninstaller is returning immediately, even though I'm using `ExecWait`.

I saw this page here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/When_I_use_ExecWait,_it_doesn%27t_wait which mentions why it's happening, and then offers some suggestions, but I can't get mine to work.

The code I'm trying is:

```
ExecWait '"C:\path\to\uninstall.exe" /NCRC' $0
MessageBox MB_OK "uninstaller returned $0"
```

Which shows the message box displaying "uninstaller returned 0" at the same time the uninstaller is launched.  Has anyone gotten around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you linked to talks about ExecWait in general, but it also links to [When I use ExecWait uninstaller.exe it doesn't wait for the uninstaller](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/When_I_use_ExecWait_uninstaller.exe_it_doesn%27t_wait_for_the_uninstaller), that is the NSIS specific info you are looking for ( _?=c:\theinstalldir tells nsis uninstaller not to copy itself to %temp% and execute a new (non waiting) copy there)

Comment: @Anders: I also have the same issue. I am trying `ExecWait '"C:\Program Files\My Program\unins000.exe" _?="C:\Program Files\My Program"'`...but for me it's not working. I have also put a `MessageBox MB_OK` at the end to cross-check if its working but the message box gets immediately display before the uninstallation process.

Comment: @Anders: Probably. I need to execute `unins000.exe` and wait until the uninstallation process is finished. Moreover, I am usig `ExecWait` inside my installer's normal installation section (and not in Uninstaller ). Is it somehow possible?